# Using recursive treeview components Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to implement treeview in Angular2, here is my treeview component :

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component ({
 selector: 'tree-view',
 directives: [TreeView],
 template: `
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="#node of treeData">
   {{node.name}}
   <tree-view [treeData]="node.subnodes"></tree-view>
  </li>
 </ul>
`
})
export class TreeView {
   @Input() treeData: any[];
}
```

and here is my component :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {TreeView} from './tree-view.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [TreeView],
    template: `
    <h1>Tree as UL</h1>
    <tree-view [treeData]=myTree></tree-view>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  myTree =     [
        {name:"parent1", subnodes:[]},
        {name:"parent2", 
            subnodes:[
                    {name:"parent2_child1", subnodes:[]}
                 ]},
        {name:"parent3", 
            subnodes:[
                    {name:"parent3_child1", 
                        subnodes:[
                                {name:"parent3_child1_child1", subnodes:[]}
                             ]
                    }
                 ]
        }
    ];
}
```

And here is the error I am getting :

```
localhost/:18 Error: ReferenceError: TreeView_1 is not defined(…)
```

I already tried the forwardRef solution and it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: how and why are you using `<tree-view [treeData]="node.subnodes"></tree-view>` `in TreeViewComponent`?

Comment: I am trying to do this http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0